# TSQL Pivot table rows to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've got some data in a table that looks like the following.  I'm trying to run a query that will get my data on a single row per requestId.  I don't need the dates or the denial reason just the eprojman and apvStatus for each groupId

requestId - projMan1 - apvStatus1 - projMan2 - apvStatus2 - projMan3 - apvStatus3 etc..  for all 5 groupIds

| requestId | groupId | entryDate | approvalDate | apvStatus | projMan | denialReason |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-11-02 | 2019-07-25 | APPROVED | rx1942 | NULL |
| 1 | 2 | 2020-11-02 | 2019-07-25 | APPROVED | ma2674 | NULL |
| 1 | 3 | 2020-11-02 | 2019-07-25 | APPROVED | cb9097 | NULL |
| 1 | 4 | 2020-11-02 | 2019-07-25 | APPROVED | bj1763 | NULL |
| 1 | 5 | 2020-11-02 | 2019-07-25 | APPROVED | tr5972 | NULL |
| 2 | 1 | 2020-11-02 | NULL | NOT APPROVED | NULL | 6 |
| 2 | 2 | 2020-11-02 | NULL | PENDING | ma2674 | NULL |
| 2 | 3 | 2020-11-02 | NULL | PENDING | cb9097 | NULL |
| 2 | 4 | 2020-11-02 | NULL | PENDING | bj1763 | NULL |
| 2 | 5 | 2020-11-02 | NULL | PENDING | tr5972 | NULL |

I've been trying to use a PIVOT table but all the examples I find involves summing data or something.  I just pretty much want to take the 5 rows and turn it into 1 for each requestID

The only thing I've been able to come up with is to select from the same table 5 times for each groupID and union it but that's slower than heck.  Got to be a better way

Thanks.

Current query:

```
select group1.requestId
    , group1.apvStatus as apvStatus1
    , group1.projMan as projMan1
    , group2.apvStatus as apvStatus2
    , group2.projMan as projMan2
    , group3.apvStatus as apvStatus3
    , group3.projMan as projMan3
    ,group4.apvStatus as apvStatus4
    , group4.projMan as projMan4
    ,group5.apvStatus as apvStatus5
    , group5.projMan as projMan5
    ,group1.denialReason 
    INTO #TEMPBAOrganized
    from (
    select requestId, apvStatus, projMan, denialReason from #TEMPBULKAPPROVAL where groupId = 1) group1
    INNER JOIN 
    (select requestId, apvStatus, projMan, denialReason from #TEMPBULKAPPROVAL where groupId = 2) group2
    on group1.requestId = group2.requestId
    INNER JOIN
    (select requestId, apvStatus, projMan from #TEMPBULKAPPROVAL where groupId = 3) group3
    on group1.requestId = group3.requestId
    INNER JOIN
    (select requestId, apvStatus, projMan from #TEMPBULKAPPROVAL where groupId = 4) group4
    on group1.requestId = group4.requestId
    INNER JOIN
    (select requestId, apvStatus, projMan from #TEMPBULKAPPROVAL where groupId = 5) group5
    on group1.requestId = group5.requestId
```

Comment: please do not post image, use formatted text. Also include your current query

Answer (score 1):

For pivoting of multiple column, it is easier to use `CASE` expression with aggregate.

```
select  t.requestId,
        projMan1    = max(case when t.groupId = 1 then t.projMan end),
        apvStatus1  = max(case when t.groupId = 1 then t.apvStatus end),
        projMan2    = max(case when t.groupId = 2 then t.projMan end),
        apvStatus2  = max(case when t.groupId = 2 then t.apvStatus end),
        projMan3    = max(case when t.groupId = 3 then t.projMan end),
        apvStatus3  = max(case when t.groupId = 3 then t.apvStatus end),
        projMan4    = max(case when t.groupId = 4 then t.projMan end),
        apvStatus4  = max(case when t.groupId = 4 then t.apvStatus end),
        projMan5    = max(case when t.groupId = 5 then t.projMan end),
        apvStatus5  = max(case when t.groupId = 5 then t.apvStatus end)
from    #TEMPBULKAPPROVAL t
group by t.requestId
```

Note : `max` is also an aggregate function

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with something like this:

```
SELECT
    requestId,
    approvalDate_1 = MAX(approvalDate_1),
    approvalDate_2 = MAX(approvalDate_2),
    approvalDate_3 = MAX(approvalDate_3),
    approvalDate_4 = MAX(approvalDate_4),
    approvalDate_5 = MAX(approvalDate_5), 
    projMan_1 = MAX(projMan_1),
    projMan_2 = MAX(projMan_2),
    projMan_3 = MAX(projMan_3),
    projMan_4 = MAX(projMan_4),
    projMan_5 = MAX(projMan_5)
FROM
(
SELECT
    requestId,
    groupId, 
    approvalDate,
    projMan,
    'approvalDate_' + CAST( groupId AS VARCHAR(2)) AS approvalDatePivot,
    'projMan_' + CAST( groupId AS VARCHAR(2)) AS projManPivot
FROM
  @tbl
) T
PIVOT (
  MAX(approvalDate) FOR approvalDatePivot IN ([approvalDate_1],[approvalDate_2],[approvalDate_3],[approvalDate_4],[approvalDate_5])
) pvt_1
PIVOT (
  MAX(projMan) FOR projManPivot IN ([projMan_1],[projMan_2],[projMan_3],[projMan_4],[projMan_5])
) pvt_2

GROUP BY requestId
```

Comment: The use of `DENSE_RANK()` only makes sense if all five `group_id` values are guaranteed to always exist, and never had values below 1.  In which case you may as well just use `group_id`...

Comment: agreed, but with just `group_id` how do you distinguish the column names resulting from the 2 pivots?

Comment: Still use the concatenation in your sub-query, just concatenate the group_id rather than the dense_rank?